# Sitecore MVC Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am pretty new at sitecore and i faced a problem when rendering controller.

As you can see from below picture i created a "Mainlayout" and putted the placeholders.

```html
  <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    
                    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content")
                    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content1")
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
```

After that i created a class Driver which contains Name and Text properties

```
public class Driver
  {
       public HtmlString  Name { get; set; }
       public HtmlString  Text { get; set; }
   }
```

The third picture has a method for getting the driver.

```
public class DriverRepository
{
   public Driver GetDriver()
   {
        var driver = new Driver();

        var rendering = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering;

        var datasource = rendering.Item;

        driver.Name =  new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(datasource, "Name"));
        driver.Text = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(datasource, "Text"));

        return driver;
    }
}
```

After that i created a controller Driver with actionresult Featured

```
public class DriverController : Controller {
// GET: Driver  public ActionResult Featured()    {
    var repository = new DriverRepository();

    var driver = repository.GetDriver();


    return View(driver);
}

}
```

And generated the view for the controller

```
using Sitecore.Mvc 
model TestMvcTaulantTutorial.Models.Driver 

Name : Model.Name <br /> 
Text : Model.Text
```

After that in sitecore I created a controller rendering for the Driver controller

I specified to home page this rendering to be read to content1

But when I deploy it returns me this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'TestMvcTaulantTutorial.Models.Driver', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel'.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837256/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-sitecore-mvc-presentation

Comment: "And generated the view for the controller" can you show us the View?

Comment: Here is the generated view

Comment: using Sitecore.Mvc
model TestMvcTaulantTutorial.Models.Driver

    Name : Model.Name
    <br />

    Text : Model.Text

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong here. Even tried to reproduce.. are you sure you used a Controller Rendering and not a View Rendering?

Comment: Have you specified the Model field on the Controller rendering item to be TestMvcTaulantTutorial.Models.Driver?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** My first assumption, as far as I understood from your description, seems that your rendering is not re-deployed and you are having a previous version of the same rendering at your deployment target, because dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel' while you have clearly specified correct model at the top:

```
    model TestMvcTaulantTutorial.Models.Driver
```

... so that's probably another rendering being taken.

**2.** Another assumption, could you please replace that:

```
    return View(driver);
```

.. with thу code below, explicitly specifying your view path, just to understand wether that is a root of a problem:

```
    return View("your_correct_view_path", driver);
```

**3.** Also, what I've noticed, on a view you should have:

```
    Name : @Model.Name <br/>
    Text : @Model.Text
```

instead of:

```
    Name : Model.Name <br/>
    Text : Model.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

The Driver class should inherit from RenderingModel class.

```
public class Driver:  Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Rvan is right. That error caused you to create the view rendering and not the controller rendering. Remember in the naming convention you don't need the `controller` keyword after the controller's name.